# Monitor redetect needed at random

Tags: windows-7, display

Have a user with a fairly normal desktop (HP Pro 3305 MT, Windows 7) and a LG W2261 monitor.

Periodically (ie randomly) on bootup the monitor has reverted to being installed as a 'Generic PnP monitor' and the display reverts back to a standard resolution (along with reorganising the desktop).

As soon as you click 'Detect' in Display properties the monitor is redetected correctly and changes the resolution accordingly. I've installed the LG drivers for the monitor (rather than the default Windows ones) and it is still happening; probably 3 times in the last month.

We have several of these desktops with no problems, but only one of these monitors! Any suggestions on turning off the 'detect'?

*As it happens at boot: i've blamed the user for switching on with the monitor turned off - yet he assures me this morning that he didn't!*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The monitor being off when the computer was turned on was my first thought. It may also be a barely-working cable - the pin that sends EDID is not quite up to snuff. Try changing cable and see if that helps. The inputs or outputs on computer or monitor could also be to blame as well.

Comment: The PC is only a few months old, the monitor is older so may be to blame, i'll swap cables and possibly inputs to see if it makes any difference, thanks! :)

Comment: Swapped cables soon after my previous comment. Issue has not resurfaced! Thanks :)